# IFrame: AutoComplete Suggestion Not working in Firefox. Its working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i have 1 iFrame, in this to load autocomplete suggestion not working in firefox, but it is working in IE, below is my code.

Any Help??

```
function loadAutoCompleteData() {
    $(window.frames['offlineCandFrame'].document.getElementById('EmpCity')).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var countryName = document.frames('offlineCandFrame').document.getElementById('controlId_3005').options[document.frames('offlineCandFrame').document.getElementById('controlId_3005').selectedIndex].text;
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxZoniacURL,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    api: "ajaxRequestPost",
                    interfaceName: "SingleListHandler",
                    methodName: "autoCompleteLookup",
                    id: "1",
                    controlName : "controlId_3007",
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Why don't you add the autocomplete in the iframe itself?

Comment: No there is no error.. autocomplete suggestion for location.

Comment: if i put alert after Line : 3 - it was not shown.

Comment: You're not doing something in your success function. Are you sure it's working in *any* browser?

Comment: yes it is working. i missed come code in success. but my issue is not there. my issue is in the line 3 !!!!